# How to make timer irq work on QEMU(-machine virt -cpu cortex-a57)

Tags: timer, qemu, arm64, bare-metal

I am trying timer interrupt on QEMU (-machine virt -cpu cortex-a57), but still fail until now. I have several questions and need your suggestion, I am very appreciate your help.

> [Fixed] The problem is fixed in [armv8-bare-metal](https://github.com/NienfengYao/armv8-bare-metal) (commit
>   7aaa433576602b93d426f63b1a8a9fe473a52506). I can get the correct
>   exception (with GDB) based timer IRQ. The root cause is missing GIC setting.

1. Is there any simple example for me reference? Or where should I ask the question?
2. Someone can give me some suggestions in my current study [armv8-bare-metal](https://github.com/NienfengYao/armv8-bare-metal) (commit b72c6a8cc7033a4fed89b57f75826d201466179f)? 
   Current status is that we can see the CNTV_CTL_EL0:bit2(ISTATUS) changes but the irq_interrupt handle call back function doesn't be called, and we also don't observe any changes in ISR_EL1(there is no IRQ interrupt pending detected).

2-1. I update the procedure, add gic configuration. But still doesn't work. Need help. [armv8-bare-metal](https://github.com/NienfengYao/armv8-bare-metal) (commit 80cdcd3aec00942b5af28acaf350c136abf1a730)?

The procedure/log is below.

```
$ make run
qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -cpu cortex-a57 -nographic -kernel kernel.elf

/* init_gicd( ) */
REG_GIC_GICD_CTLR: 0x00000000 08000000 = 0x00000000 00000000
Write REG_GIC_GICD_ICENABLER:
0x00000000 08000180 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000184 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
Write REG_GIC_GICD_ICPENDR:
0x00000000 08000280 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000284 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
REG_GIC_GICD_IPRIORITYR:
0x00000000 08000400 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000404 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000408 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 0800040C = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000410 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000414 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000418 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 0800041C = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000420 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000424 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000428 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 0800042C = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000430 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000434 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 08000438 = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
0x00000000 0800043C = 0x00000000 FFFFFFFF
REG_GIC_GICD_ITARGETSR:
0x00000000 08000820 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000824 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000828 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 0800082C = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000830 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000834 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000838 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 0800083C = 0x00000000 00000000
REG_GIC_GICD_ICFGR:
0x00000000 08000C04 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000C08 = 0x00000000 00000000
0x00000000 08000C0C = 0x00000000 00000000
REG_GIC_GICD_CTLR: 0x00000000 08000000 = 0x00000000 00000001

/* init_gicc( ) */
GICC_CTLR: 0x00000000 08010000 = 0x00000000 00000000
REG_GIC_GICC_PMR: 0x00000000 08010004 = 0x00000000 000000FF
REG_GIC_GICC_BPR : 0x00000000 08010008 = 0x00000000 00000000
REG_GIC_GICC_EOI : Clear all of the active interrupts
REG_GIC_GICC_CTLR : 0x00000000 08010000 = 0x00000000 00000001

/* gicd_enable_int(27) */
REG_GIC_GICD_ISENABLER: 0x00000000 08000100 = 0x00000000 0800FFFF

/* Virtual Timer config */
CurrentEL = 0x00000000 00000004    /* EL1 */
DAIF = 0x00000000 000003C0         /* DAIF bits are set */
CNTV_CTL_EL0 = 0x00000000 00000000
Disable the timer, CNTV_CTL_EL0 = 0x00000000 00000000 /* Clear bits of ENABLE/IMASK */
CNTFRQ_EL0 = 0x00000000 03B9ACA0   /* frequency of the system counter = 62.5MHz */ 
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x00000000 000242C5   /* current 64-bit virtual count value */
Set it as next 1 sec, CNTV_CVAL_EL0 = 0x00000000 03BBEF65 /* set compare value */
Enable the timer, CNTV_CTL_EL0 = 0x00000000 00000001  /* Set bit ENABLE */
Enable IRQ, DAIF = 0x00000000 00000340  /* Clear IRQ mask bit */

/* we observe the CNTVCT_EL0 and CNTV_CTL_EL0 */
/* if time up, CNTV_CTL_EL0[2] = 1 */
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x00000000 000390CA, CNTV_CTL_EL0 = 0x00000000 00000001
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x00000000 0003D41F, CNTV_CTL_EL0 = 0x00000000 00000001
...
/* time up, CNTV_CTL_EL0[2]: ISTATUS = 1*/
CNTVCT_EL0 = 0x00000000 03BCE5C4, CNTV_CTL_EL0 = 0x00000000 00000005
SPSR_EL1 = 0x00000000 00000000
ISR_EL1 = 0x00000000 00000000
/* But the irq_handler doesn't be called and ISR_EL1[7] = 0 */
/* there is no IRQ interrupt pending detected */
QEMU: Terminated
```

Comment: 1. Here is an [example][1] from ARM Trusted Firmware that uses timer related registers to generate time IRQ and handle it.

2. Share your output with each step to show how does your timer fail.

  [1]: https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/bl32/tsp/tsp_timer.c

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks all. The problem is fixed, I can get the correct exception based the timer IRQ.